# How to filter an object using values of an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6

i have an object like this (this is how we see the object in chrome dev tools for example):

```
obj: {
  1: {...},
  2: {...},
  3: {...},
  4: {...},
  5: {...},
}
```

And i have a simple array like this:

```
arr: [1,3,5,7]
```

Basically i want my object to stay just with the keys that are in the array, like this:

```
obj: {
  1: {...},
  3: {...},
  5: {...},
}
```

At the moment my code is this:

```
var select = (arr, obj) => arr.reduce((r, e) => 
  Object.assign(r, obj[e] ? { [e]: obj[e] } : null)
, {});

var output = select(arr, obj);
```

I dont know why but this sometimes works and other times don´t. I can not use Jquery.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: whats the `enter code here`? And when does it not work? you have example data? the code looks good

Comment: Your code is fine. What errors do you encountered when it doesn't work?

Comment: `obj[e] ?` is not a proper check (cause falsy values might not be what you want to check for). `e in obj ?` would be more accurate.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter out the keys that are not inside `arr`:

```js
const obj ={
  1: {},
  2: {},
  3: {},
  4: {},
  5: {},
};

const arr = [1, 3, 5, 7];

const filtered = Object.fromEntries(
  // Note `key` is an `string` here, thus the `+`:
  Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => arr.includes(+key))
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Or a simple `for` loop, [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) in this case, again with [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to pick the ones you want (rather than filtering those you don't) and [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to avoid adding keys that don't exist in `obj`:

```js
const obj ={
  1: {},
  2: {},
  3: {},
  4: {},
  5: {},
};

const arr = [1, 3, 5, 7];

const filtered = {};

for (const key of arr) { 
  // Note the `hasOwnProperty` check here to avoid adding the key `7` with a value of `undefined`:
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) filtered[key] = obj[key];
}

console.log(filtered);
```

Or you could do this same thing using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const obj ={
  1: {},
  2: {},
  3: {},
  4: {},
  5: {},
};

const arr = [1, 3, 5, 7];

const filtered = arr.reduce((newObj, key) => {
  // Note we add the values to `newObj` rather than `filtered` now:
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) newObj[key] = obj[key];
  
  // And you always need to return `newObj`:
  return newObj;
}, { })

console.log(filtered);
```

Lastly, if you are already using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), you could use [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#pick):

```js
const obj ={
  1: {},
  2: {},
  3: {},
  4: {},
  5: {},
};

const arr = [1, 3, 5, 7];

const filtered = _.pick(obj, arr);

console.log(filtered);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.core.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In a modern environment (or with appropriate polyfills), you'd use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), like this:

```
const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([key, value]) => arr.includes(+key))
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
  1: {name: "one"},
  2: {name: "two"},
  3: {name: "three"},
  4: {name: "four"},
  5: {name: "five"},
};

const arr = [1,3,5,7];

const result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj)
        .filter(([key, value]) => arr.includes(+key))
);

console.log(result);
```

...but you can also take a simple loop approach:

```
const result = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (arr.includes(+key)) {
        result[key] = value;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
  1: {name: "one"},
  2: {name: "two"},
  3: {name: "three"},
  4: {name: "four"},
  5: {name: "five"},
};

const arr = [1,3,5,7];

const result = {};
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (arr.includes(+key)) {
        result[key] = value;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

---

In both of the above, note that `+` before `key` in the `filter` call. The array contains *numbers*, but the property keys of objects are always either strings or Symbols (strings, in your case). So we have to convert for `includes` to find them.